# Prove that gcd(m, n) | lcm(n, m) for any non-zero integers m, n

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if you could help me with this question, in discrete math.

Prove that gcd(m, n) | lcm(n, m) for any non-zero integers m, n

any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should show any work that you've already done.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By definition, $\gcd(m,n)$ is a common divisor of both $m$ and $n$, and $\text{lcm}(m,n)$ is a common multiple of both $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$gcd(m,n) \mid m$, and $m \mid lcm(m, n)$. The *divides* relation "$\mid$" is transitive. Thus the result.